# JSON_REMOVE MYSQL имена с тире

Tags: mysql, json

В колонке uuid_session хранится json

```
["e4d698ce-8596-443b-9eea-b8aac841340c", "test"]
```

Элемент test я легко удаляю с помощью

```
UPDATE test SET uuid_sessions = JSON_REMOVE(uuid_sessions, '$.test')
```

Но как мне удалить элемент e4d698ce-8596-443b-9eea-b8aac841340c ?

Эти запросы не приносят результата:

```
UPDATE test SET uuid_sessions = JSON_REMOVE(uuid_sessions, '$.e4d698ce-8596-443b-9eea-b8aac841340c')
UPDATE test SET uuid_sessions = JSON_REMOVE(uuid_sessions, '$."e4d698ce-8596-443b-9eea-b8aac841340c"')
```

Comment: Я не понимаю как ваш первый пример работает. я попытался его воспроизвести и у меня json_remove ничего не удаляет с помощью `$.test`. Собственно по документации MySQL так и должно быть. `$.test` означает элемент с именем test в объекте, а не элемент массива с содержимым test. MySQL позволяет работать с элементами массивов только по числовым индексам в квадратных скобках